# Slicing strings to meet if conditions

Tags: python, string, dictionary, debugging

I have a series of conditions that pluralise words. Conditions for if they are found in the file, and conditions if they are not found in the file. I have (I think) indentified my problem but unsure how to fix it. I'm sure its related to how im slicing strings to match conditions.

I believe you can read all prior to `else:` so I will jump ahead.
all following `else` aims to in order of:
**if word not in plural, and not a proper noun, then: if word ends with vowel, add 's'. *Otherwise*;

-if ends with 'y' and is preceded by a consonant, erase the last letter and add 'ies'.

-if ends with 'f', erase the last letter and add 'ves'

-if ends with 'sh'/'ch'/'z', add 'es'

-if none of the above applies, just add 's'.**

logic must follow the order above and cannot deviate.

```
def pluralize(word):
  proper_nouns= [line.strip() for line in open (filepath)]    ### opens file when function is called, removes white spaces, and returns a list of the content within the file. 
  word_in_plural = ''                                         ### placeholders for string values.
  x = ''
  vowels = ('aeiou')                                          ### variables to apply conditional statements
  consonants = ('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz')
  dictionary = {'plural' : word_in_plural, 'status' : x}      ### dictionary definition
  if word == '':                                              
    dictionary ['plural'] = ''; dictionary ['status'] = 'empty_string'

  elif word [-1] == 's':                                     
    dictionary ['plural'] = word; dictionary ['status'] = 'already_in_plural'

  elif word.lower() in proper_nouns:                                  
    dictionary ['plural'] = word; dictionary ['status'] = 'proper_noun'

  else: 
    
   if word [-1].lower() in vowels:                                    #works
     word = word + 's' 
     dictionary ['plural'] = word; dictionary ['status'] = 'success'
        

   elif word [-2].lower() in consonants and word[-1] == 'y':          #works
     word = word [:-1] + 'ies'
     dictionary ['plural'] = word; dictionary ['status'] = 'success'
      

   elif word [-1].lower() == 'f':                                      #works
     word = word [:-1] + 'ves'
     dictionary ['plural'] = word; dictionary ['status'] = 'success'
      

   elif word [-1:-2].lower() == 's' + 'h' or 'c' + 'h':               #does not
     word = word + 'es'
     dictionary ['plural'] = word; dictionary ['status'] = 'success'
      

   elif word [:-1].lower() == 'z':                                    #works
     word = word + 'es'
     dictionary ['plural'] = word; dictionary ['status'] = 'success'
      

   elif word not in proper_nouns.lower():                             #not sure
     word = word + 's'
     dictionary ['plural'] = word; dictionary ['status'] = 'success'
```

output:

```
failure --> {'plural': 'failures', 'status': 'success'}
----
food --> {'plural': 'foodes', 'status': 'success'}
----
Zulma --> {'plural': 'Zulma', 'status': 'proper_noun'}
----
injury --> {'plural': 'injuries', 'status': 'success'}
----
elf --> {'plural': 'elves', 'status': 'success'}
----
buzz --> {'plural': 'buzzes', 'status': 'success'}
----
computers --> {'plural': 'computers', 'status': 'already_in_plural'}
----
PCs --> {'plural': 'PCs', 'status': 'already_in_plural'}
----
 --> {'plural': '', 'status': 'empty_string'}
----
highway --> {'plural': 'highwayes', 'status': 'success'}
----
presentation --> {'plural': 'presentationes', 'status': 'success'}
----
pouch --> {'plural': 'pouches', 'status': 'success'}
----
COVID-19 --> {'plural': 'COVID-19es', 'status': 'success'}
----
adam --> {'plural': 'adam', 'status': 'proper_noun'}
```

food , highways, presentations and covid-19 is wrong. They are not in the file so should end with 's'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) Specifically regarding your `es` case

Comment: not specifically, but I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
elif (word [-1:-2].lower() == 's' + 'h') or (word [-1:-2].lower() == 'c' + 'h'):
```

Comment: thanks bud, but that creates another problem: 
```buzz --> {'plural': 'buzzs', 'status': 'success'}```
```pouch --> {'plural': 'pouchs', 'status': 'success'}```
now fails to do as expected